# Encode string params in rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In this when I am passing phone as string in params rails api, it is being passed in the form of `"\"9650661678\""`. How to use escape string or how to encode it so that only string can be entered as input.
Any help will be welcomed ! Thanks in advance.
clients_controller.rb

```
def myzenica
    mobile = params[:phone]
    client = Client.where(:phone => mobile)
    render :json => client
end
```

```
terminal
Started GET "/clients/myzenica?phone=%229650661678%22" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-15 11:21:23 +0530
Processing by ClientsController#myzenica as */*
  Parameters: {"phone"=>"\"9650661678\"", "client"=>{}}
  Client Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `clients`.* FROM `clients` WHERE `clients`.`phone` = '\"9650661678\"'
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

Comment: in which way you are passing params? using curl or what?

Comment: I am a ruby on rails beginner. Does nt know much about it. I am using params[:phone] in controller to take phone from the user through api. And in postman my output is just [ ]. because phone is passing as '\"9650661678\""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CGI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html).

```
require 'cgi'
CGI.escape('%229650661678%22')
 => "\"9650661678\""
```

UPDATE:

```
def myzenica
  require 'cgi'
  mobile = CGI.escape(params[:phone])
  client = Client.where(:phone => mobile) 
  render :json => client
end
```

NOTE:
  In your input field which is on `postman` on your side. You should enter a text without double/single qoutes. Because postman field is just like input field on html tags. It will treat it all as string.

Comment: used it like                                                                                                def myzenica
    mobile = CGI.escape(params[:phone])
  client = Client.where(:phone => mobile)
    render :json => client

  end   but this did not work.

Comment: Did you added `require 'cgi'`?

Comment: I updated my answer above, check if you do it like that. And if don't tell me what is the response.

Comment: still it is taking params as  Parameters: {"phone"=>"\"9650661678\"", "client"=>{}}    :(

Comment: Ok, what you are trying to do? Do you want to receive in `params` like this `%229650661678%22`? Or like this `\"9650661678\"
`?

Comment: It is get api. In my database phone no.is 9650661678 and i am storing it as string in db. now when i am getting it from user through api. I want it as 9650661678 only not with any backslash

Comment: What  did you enter in your `postman` input? Is it just `9650661678` or `"9650661678"`?

Comment: I was doing it wrong. i have solved my problem. actually there was no issue related to this.

Comment: was passing "9650661678" but it should be 9650661678. Now its working.

Comment: Yes. Thats why I asked you that question. Please accept/check my answer.